# Decoding System.config.js from Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, package.json

H All,
Below is a snippet of system.config.js file used in Angular2.
I can see a lot of options in the config file, some I can understand some I cant. Nowhere I can find reference which explains all options in simple language
Below I have mentioned what options I understood, request you all to please confirm if I understood them correctly or not ?
Please share the meaning of the unknown ones mentioned below in capitals.

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'ts', --> Transpiler to be used as browser can't understand typescript.
                           String 'ts' is the reference to the plugin added in maps

    typescriptOptions: {  --> When using type typescript, whether to add 
                              some configuration. File name can only be tsconfig.json
      tsconfig: true
    },

    meta: { --> DON'T KNOW WHAT IS THE USE OF THIS ?
      'typescript': {
        "exports": "ts"
      }
    },

    paths: { --> DON'T KNOW WHAT IS THE USE OF THIS ? CAN THIS BE PLACED IN MAP ? 
             Looks like a key-value pair
      'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
    },

    map: { --> Basically a Key-value pair. When called 'main', 'main.js' is loaded
      app: 'app',
      'main': 'main.js',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api':  'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'ts':                         'npm:plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js',
      'typescript':                 'npm:typescript@2.0.3/lib/typescript.js',
    },

    packages: { --> Again a key-value pair with default loading file. 
                   Means when ONLY 'app/core' is called,url becomes '/app/core/main.js'

      'app/core': { main: 'index' },
      'app/models': { main: 'index' },
      'api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
      app: {
        main: './main.ts',
        defaultExtension: 'ts'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Are their any other important options that I missed out ?
If yes please share them as well with their significance.

Comment: That file is configuration for SystemJS - dynamic script loader for ES/JS. Documentation: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs In most cases you don't need to update that file. Just add more libs into mapping

Comment: @A.Tim I am interested in knowing the purpose of the config options and their usage rather than just copy pasting and forgetting about it